# Different output in sparse representation as compared to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp




def func1(A,c,eps,maxiter):
    c=0.8
    eps=1e-4
    maxiter=20
    n=sc.shape(A)[0]                   
    sim=sc.eye(n)
    sim_prev=sc.zeros((n,n))    
    I=sc.eye(n)
    P= normalize(A, norm='l1', axis=0)    
    Q=P*(1-sc.exp(-A))        
    for t in range(maxiter):

        sim=c*(sc.dot(Q.T,sim)) + (1-c)*I

    return sim


def func2(A,c,maxiter):
    c=0.8
    eps=1e-4
    maxiter=20
    n=sp.csr_matrix.get_shape(A)[0]    
    sim=sp.eye(n)    
    I=sp.eye(n)
    P= normalize(A, norm='l1', axis=0) 

    Q =-(P*(np.expm1(-A)))

    for t in range(maxiter):


        sim=c*(sc.dot(Q.T,sim)) + (1-c)*I

    return sim
```

Given above are two functions which are essentially the same except func1 is for numpy array and func2 is for scipy sparse representation of data.Since I am dealing with big data now thats why I wanted to convert my code to sparse representation but the output is coming different for the same input.

```
  A=sc.array([[0,1,1,0,1],[1,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0]]) #pass this to the func1
    sA = sp.csr_matrix(A)#pass this to func2


output of the sparse func2
(0, 0)        3292.45824232
(0, 3)        777.213797401
(1, 1)        0.798590816646
(1, 2)        0.244114817184
(1, 4)        0.244114817184
(2, 1)        0.244114817184
(2, 2)        0.205180591139
(2, 4)        0.105180591139
(3, 0)        777.213797401
(3, 3)        183.603052715
(4, 1)        0.244114817184
(4, 2)        0.105180591139
(4, 4)        0.205180591139


output of func1

[[ 0.13890945  0.0314584   0.02635767  0.00893873  0.02635767]
 [ 0.04718761  0.12997072  0.00893873  0.03698614  0.00893873]
 [ 0.07907301  0.01787747  0.11498536  0.00510073  0.01498536]
 [ 0.0268162   0.07397228  0.00510073  0.12103198  0.00510073]
 [ 0.07907301  0.01787747  0.01498536  0.00510073  0.11498536]]
```

Comment: Fill in fake-data (for A and c), and also your imports. This makes debugging much easier. The obvious first step is to add prints after each line and look for the first difference to occur. And i assume you did check your math in regards to the +P -P-stuff

Comment: @sascha yes the math at +P -P is correct

Comment: @sascha I added all the relevant information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did use elementwise matrix-multiplication in the dense-one, matrix-multiplication in the sparse one!

It boils down to `A*B` meaning different things in terms of numpy-arrays and scipy.sparse matrices. As this is dependent on the shapes in use, i'm a bit scared about giving general rules and just recommend reading the docs of numpy and scipy.sparse (simplified: A * B = elementwise-multiplication for numpy-array, while A.dot(B) matrix-multiplication; A * B = matrix-multiplication for sparse matrices).

Change (**sparse-version only**):

```
Q =-(P*(np.expm1(-A)))            # matrix-multiplication
```

to:

```
Q =-(P.multiply(np.expm1(-A)))    # elementwise-multiplication
```

which outputs:

```
dense
[[0.25619944 0.04951776 0.04318623 0.01252072 0.04318623]
 [0.07427664 0.24367873 0.01252072 0.06161358 0.01252072]
 [0.12955869 0.02504144 0.22183936 0.00633153 0.02183936]
 [0.03756215 0.12322716 0.00633153 0.23115801 0.00633153]
 [0.12955869 0.02504144 0.02183936 0.00633153 0.22183936]]
sparse
[[0.25619944 0.04951776 0.04318623 0.01252072 0.04318623]
 [0.07427664 0.24367873 0.01252072 0.06161358 0.01252072]
 [0.12955869 0.02504144 0.22183936 0.00633153 0.02183936]
 [0.03756215 0.12322716 0.00633153 0.23115801 0.00633153]
 [0.12955869 0.02504144 0.02183936 0.00633153 0.22183936]]
```

Comment: sim=c*(sc.dot(Q.T,sim)) + (1-c)*I  will this line change too in sparse multiplication ?

Comment: Just change the one line i showed! Numpy's dot is the equivalent to matrix-multiplication for compatible shapes! And scipy.sparse will do mat-mul too with dot. Read the docs on those to get a feeling.

Comment: @ChaitaliSarkar That code was indeed something interesting to see for me. I never did look at this expm1-function and checking it out, including your outer negation, makes a lot of sense to me now (especially the existence of expm1 and the missing (not without reason) exp for sparse-matrices!) So i learned something too!